# Verifying an indefinite integral solution

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I'm working on indefinite integrals right now. I'm given the problem

> $$\int(\frac{8}{x}-\frac{5}{x^2}+\frac{6}{x^3}) dx$$

My worksheet gives the answer $8\ln(x)+\frac{5}{x}-\frac{3}{x^2}+c$

I'm trying to figure out if my answer is correct in a different form. So I tried making my solution equal to the given solution to test it, but so far I don't think that has worked. Here's how I approached this problem:

\begin{align*}
\int\frac{8}{x}dx&=8\int\frac{1}{x}dx \implies 8\ln(|x|) \\
\int-\frac{5}{x^2}dx&=-5\int\frac{1}{x}dx \implies -5\ln(|x^2|) \\ \int\frac{6}{x^3}dx&=6\int\frac{1}{x^3}dx \implies6\ln(|x^3|) \\ &= 8\ln(x)-5\ln(x^2)+6\ln(x^3) \\ &= \ln(x^8)-\ln(x^2)^5+\ln(x^3)^{6} \\ &= \frac{\ln(x)^8}{\ln(x)^{10}}+\ln(x)^{18} \\ &= \ln(\frac{1}{x^2}+\ln(x)^{18}) \\ &= -2\ln(x)+18\ln(x) \\ &= 16\ln(x)+c
\end{align*}

Comment: $\int x^n\,dx =\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ when $n\neq -1$.

Comment: Try differentiating each of the three terms. See if you get what you ought to get.

Comment: No!  How did you change $$\require{color}\int-\frac5{x^{\color{red}2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ to $$-5\int\frac1{x}\,\mathrm{d}x?$$

Comment: @user10354138 Oh when I took the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ I should have made it $\frac{1}{2x^4}$ now that I look back at it. Okay so I see one mistake I made so far

Answer (score 2):

Careful!

The primitive of $x^a$ is $\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}$ for all $a\neq -1$.

Only for $a=-1$ we have that the primitive is $\ln(|x|)$.

Comment: Ah I see that now. I totally overlooked the constraint that a cannot equal negative one. I'll try the problem again with that in mind!

Answer (score 0):

**You have to use this:**

$\int x^{n} dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +c \; \: \: \: \mathit{where \: n \neq -1}$

The full integral would be like this: 
$ 8\int \frac{1}{x} dx = 8\ln |x| + c $

$ 5\int x^{-2} dx = 5*\frac{x^{-2+1}}{-2+1} = \frac{-5}{x} + c $

$ 6\int x^{-3} dx = 6*\frac{x^{-3+1}}{-3+1} = \frac{-3}{x^{2}} + c  $

All together: 
 
 
$8\ln |x| + \frac{5}{x} - \frac{3}{x^{2}} + c$

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is incorrect because $$\int -\frac{5}{x^2} \, dx \neq \int -\frac{5}{x} \, dx$$just like $$\int\frac{6}{x^3} \, dx \neq \int \frac{6}{x} \, dx.$$
You have to use the power rule $\int x^a \, dx = \frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}.$
The reason why $\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln{x}:$

An integral of a function $f(x)$ is such that the derivative of the integral is the function $f(x)$.
The derivative of $\ln{x}$ is derived using implicit differentiation:
$$y=\ln{x}$$
$$e^y=x$$Now if we take the derivative:
$$e^y*\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
Because $y=\ln{x}$: $$x\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x} \text{QED}$$

Comment: Do you need to know why $\int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln{x}$?

Comment: @Maximillian that'd be nice, sure. However the second integral in your post seems to be a typo because an integral is always equal to itself.

Comment: I edited the post.